# Any JetBrains IDE: How can I map Ctrl + Mouse Wheel to Page Up / Down actions?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Or more generic, how do I map mouse shortcuts (as opposed to keyboard shortcuts)?

(used to this behavior from Eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any issues here, at all (at very least for the <kbd>Ctrl + Mouse Wheel</kbd> shortcuts).

*Screenshots are from PhpStorm 2020.3.2 on Windows 10 x64.*

1. `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`
2. Find the desired action (use the search box to filter available actions)

   [image]
3. Right click and choose the right option (`Add Mouse Shortcut`):

   [image]
4. Use the desired "mouse shortcut" there (press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and do <kbd>Mouse Wheel Up</kbd>):

   [image]
5. Apply and start using it:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I overlooked the `Add Mouse Shortcut`...

Comment: This moves the caret, too (I wish there was a way not to).

Comment: @user66081 There are `Scroll Page Up/Down` actions available. It just they are not under the expected `Editor Actions`  node (just like others) but rather under `Other | Scroll` node which is down below... Try them -- may do what you want (have not tried them myself)